# How to declare optional date field in XSD

Tags: asp.net, xml

I was using XSD to validate my incoming XML elements. 
XSD File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.rg/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:tns="http://xxxy/ervices/V0" 
targetNamespace="http://xxxy/ervices/V" elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" >

<xs:complexType name="FailType"> 
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ConDt" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"     nillable="true"/>
  <xs:element name="PreEn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:schema>
```

My XML File

```
<Pat xmlns="http://xxxy/ervices/V">
<ConDt></ConDt>
</Pat>
```

I was getting element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://org/2001/XMLSchema:date' - The string '' is not a valid Date value.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying nillable="true" allows your instance to contain

```
<ConDt xsi:nil="true"></ConDt>
```

but it doesn't allow you to write

```
<ConDt></ConDt>
```

(Please don't ask me what they were thinking...)

If you want to allow

```
<ConDt></ConDt>
```

Then two possible approaches are

1. define it as a union type that allows either an xs:date or a
   zero-length string, or
2. (my preferred approach) define it as a list type: a list of xs:date values with maxLength="1".

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Where I have to write this line <ConDt xsi:nil="true"></ConDt>  in XSD file ?

Comment: That element appears in the instance document, not in the schema.

Comment: Michel Could you guide me where I have to write list type. I was using element in side the complex type.

Comment: You currently declare ConDt to have type xs:date. Declare it instead to have type "optionalDate" and include a global type declaration for "optionalDate". Define this as a restriction (with the facet maxLength="1") of another type "listOfDates" which is a list type with itemType="xs:date".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Michael. I really appreciate your help.

Below code will allow us to declare optional date field.

```
   <xs:element name="ConDt" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0" />
            <xs:maxLength value="0" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:date" />
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```